# Decimal format in Java?

Tags: java

can someone explain to me why the output for this:

```
    double y = 15/7;
    DecimalFormat first = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
    System.out.println(y); 
    String format_string = first.format(y);
    System.out.println(format_string);
```

Is this:

```
   2.0
   2
```

(Which is wrong)

However, when I change 15/7 to

```
 15.0/7.0
```

It gives me the correct answer

```
 2.142857142857143
 2.143
```

Explanation please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers without a dot are Integers so 15/7 is an integer-operation and the result is 2 (divistion without remainder). Afterwards it gets converted to a double but keaps it's value of 2 (conversion after finishing the operation).

Numbers with dots are doubles in the first place so 15.0/7.0 is a double-operation and leads to the result you want to have (floating point division).

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
double y = 15/7;
```

with

```
double y = 15.0/7;
```

When dividing two `int`, you get an `int`.

See [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) :

> Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for
>   operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion
>   (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as large as possible
>   while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|. Moreover, q is positive when |n| ≥ |d|
>   and n and d have the same sign, but q is negative when |n| ≥ |d| and n
>   and d have opposite signs.

You convert it to a `double` by storing it in a `double` variable but that's too late : you can't get the lost precision back. The solution is to have one of the operands being a double so that you get a double when dividing.

Answer (score 3):

Division of two `integers` always results in `integer` - that's why you get `2` (`2.0` after formatting).

Division of at least one `double` gives you `double`

In your case `15/7` is a division of two integers and the result is an integer (*incorrect result*). If you change to `15/7.0` or `15.0/7` or `15.0/7.0` your result will be `double` (*correct result*)

Answer (score 1):

15/7 performs an integer division, which rounds down to the nearest integer.

15/7 = 2 + 1/7 -> gets rounded to 2

It doesn't matter that you defined y as a double, the division didn't take that into account, since it was using 2 integer literals.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `15 / 7` is `2` as it is returning the integer part of the dividing operation. If you need float values operations, do something like this: `15f / 7`.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the values are integers, so they are rounded down to 7. As the result of integer division is an integer you need to make sure you divide doubles / floats as the results of these divisions are doubles / floats which can deal with the decimal parts of the numbers

Even though you specified a double to put the result of the division into what you are actually putting in is an integer, dividing a double means the result is a double and so the answer contains the correct results.